# Netbeans 12 and TestNG with parallel tests

Tags: netbeans, testng

i'm using apache NB 12.2

I would like to use TestNG to do parallel tests, but NB it does not recognize the testng.xml file on which I indicated the tests to be done in parallel

this is the picture of NB: https://ibb.co/80Yj5jL

here I uploaded the entire project folder NB: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/9c8f21d863cd0af9e282fd1e615789e320210113182454/4d212bc4810913e630c33fc67344cc9b20210113182532/c08ff0

I did several tests, but in fact, it does not find the testng.xml file

Thanks!

Roberto.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is trivial .. to run suite test simply click on the testng.xml file with the right mouse button and choose "test" ..